# Custom Bootstrap video carousel bug next and previous controls block video controls of videos in carousel

Tags: css, video, bootstrap-4, flexbox, carousel

I'm trying to fix a bug in a video carousel. The next and previous arrow controls extend from the top to the bottom. The problem is they cover the controls for the video players themselves.

```
    .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 15%;
  flex-basis:   20%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease; }
  @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
      transition: none; } }
  .carousel-control-prev:hover, .carousel-control-prev:focus,
  .carousel-control-next:hover,
  .carousel-control-next:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.9; }

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: 0; }

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0; }

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: no-repeat 50% / 50% 50%; }
```

This is in the additional css section:

```css
.wpforms-field-container textarea {
    resize:none;
}

.site-info a {
    color:#555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .slick-track {
        max-height: calc(100vw / 2);
    }
    .slick-arrow {  
        width: 50% !important;
    }
    .carousel-control-prev {
        justify-content:flex-start !important;
    }
    .carousel-control-next {
        justify-content:flex-end !important;
    }
    
    .slick-arrow img {  
        height: 35px !important;
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the slider in action:

http://jamesautery.com/projects/music-videos/

I'm new at this so let me know if I left out any key information.

Comment: I'm not seeing the described problem, is this fixed now? Tested with Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for responding! It's not fixed yet. So if you arrow to the second video and then try to click on the play button, it goes back to the first video as if you've arrowed back. Same thing goes for the "view full screen" button, it acts as if you have clicked on the next arrow. The first video will play because there's no previous arrow to block the button.